# How should I reply if the potential supervisor ask me whether I contacted other potential supervisor?

Tags: phd, application, united-kingdom

I received a response from potential supervisor, in her response , she said ' I would, in principle be happy for you to apply to the university'. then she asked me whether I contacted with Professor xx (another potential supervisor), she said 'so I think your project will fit really well in their department! You are of course welcome to apply to more than one department, so keep me updated on what you decide to go ahead with.' How should I reply? Thank you!

Comment: Well, what do you want to do? This isn't a puzzle or test with a secret answer.

Comment: It reads like a 'suggestion' more than a serious 'question'. Did you contact the other potential supervisor? Do you think they'd be a good/better fit? I'd just do what she said -- consider your options and get back to her on what you decide to do.

Answer (score 3):

With the truth: you either contacted the other potential supervisor or did not. In the latter case, you can still contact potential supervisor B.

It is completely understandable you want to find the best project/supervisor/university/etc. for yourself (I mean 'best' in the sense that it fits you best). As long as you are open and honest about it, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I already gave thumbs up ao Aolon's answer. Just wanted to emphasize.

A PhD supervisor will be a big part of your life for several years. And hopefully it will be a life-long relationship with many positive interactions. If you stay in academe it is very likely you will want to keep a good relationship with your supervisor. It is a good thing to be as open and honest with them as possible.

At least with respect to the subject of your academic work. You may or may not want to be telling them about your personal life. That's a very different subject.

If being honest on such a point causes them to reject you, you probably did not want to work with them anyway.